# Recursively search for a file name and copy in MS DOS

Tags: recursion, batch-file, command-prompt, dos

I have a text file containing names of files separated by newline and a folder with many sub folders which would contain the files matching with names in text file.

I want to pick file names from text file which can be done using `for` loop; and recursively search for file name in the folder and if the file is found copy it to a different location.

Can anyone please shed a light on it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("file names.txt") do (
   for /f "delims=" %%b in (' dir "c:\folder\%%a" /b /s /a-d ') do (
      copy "%%b" "c:\new folder"
   )
)
```

Comment: Thanks @foxidirve, I just found that the file names inside filenames.txt provided to me does not have an extension. They are all pictures with .jpg anyway. How do I append .jpg to a file name. The command currently says 'file not found'.

Comment: All good. Got it working
`@echo on
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("e:\diff.txt") 

do (
   for /f "delims=" %%b in (' dir "e:\photos\%

%a.jpg" /b /s /a-d ') do (
      copy "%%b" "e:\new folder"
   )
)`

Answer (score 0):

Very easy (though you'll have to a bit more specific so you can tweak the code to suit your situation.

### Base Code:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("file names.txt") do (
forfiles /p "C:\users\...[path to main file]" /s /m "%%a" /c "cmd /c copy @path "C:\users\...[target path]""
```

Not sure if the above double quotes will stuff up, if it does then we can replace with a `call` and `enableextensions`.

Tell me if that doesn't work (since it will only work on Win7). Because there are many other ways to do it.

Mona